# Limit emacs skeleton pairs

Tags: org-mode, skeleton

I have the following skeleton pair setup to quickly insert LaTeX fragents into `org-mode` documents:

```
(setq skeleton-pair t)
(global-set-key (kbd "$") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
```

This works. But the trouble is that it works *everywhere*. How can I limit this behavior, so that it affects the body text of Emacs `org` documents (i.e., not applied to babel code-blocks)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't tell you anything about skeletons, you can try the following:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "$")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (if (org-in-block-p '("SRC" "EXAMPLE"))
        (self-insert-command 1)
      (self-insert-command 2)
      (backward-char))))
```

The binding works only for `org-mode` and inserts `$$` if the cursor is not in `BEGIN_SRC` or `BEGIN_EXAMPLE` blocks. Otherwise it inserts only one `$`.

You can adjust block names you want to avoid double `$` to be inserted -- I know not that much about block names in org but I believe you can figure it out.

PS
Short demo: https://youtu.be/h4Gxl0zRk5Y

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Maxim Kim